# Change existing symbol size

Tags: macros

I would like to make the `\circ` symbol smaller and centered when using it between two letters. For example, I want to say

```
\begin{align}
\forall\  a,b,c \in S,\ a\circ( b\circ c)= (a\circ b)\circ c
\end{align}
```

The default symbol is just too big for my tastes. Please bear in mind that I am a newbie.

Edit: My preamble.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
setlrmarginsandblock{1.25in}{1.0in}{1}
\setulmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout

\theoremstyle{plain} \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} \newtheorem{proposition}  {Proposition} \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma} \newtheorem*{corollary}{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{definition}{Definition} \newtheorem{conjecture}   {Conjecture} \newtheorem*{example}{Example} \newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}
\theoremstyle{remark} \newtheorem*{remark}{Remark} \newtheorem*{note}{Note}      \newtheorem{case}{Case}
\theoremstyle{algorithm} \newtheorem*{properties}{Properties}

\mathchardef\ordinarycolon\mathcode`\:
\mathcode`\:=\string"8000
\begingroup \catcode`\:=\active
\gdef:{\mathrel{\mathop\ordinarycolon}}
\endgroup

\begin{document}
\include{front_cover}
\tableofcontents
\include{lecture_3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code is not using `\circ` at all. `\cdot` is already quite small and centered. Thus make a complete example that would also show the fonts you are using.

Comment: Sorry, changed it now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm usually pretty satisfied with the size of `\circ`. But if you want it reduced you can do like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ccirc}{\mathbin{\mathchoice
  {\xcirc\scriptstyle}
  {\xcirc\scriptstyle}
  {\xcirc\scriptscriptstyle}
  {\xcirc\scriptscriptstyle}
}}
\newcommand{\xcirc}[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{$#1\circ$}}}
\begin{document}
$f\circ g$

$f\ccirc g$

$\displaystyle\lim_{f\ccirc g}$
\end{document}
```

The first line is just for comparison.

[image]

How to "exchange" the `\circ` command with the new one? Just replace the given code with

```
\let\latexcirc=\circ
\newcommand{\ccirc}{\mathbin{\mathchoice
  {\xcirc\scriptstyle}
  {\xcirc\scriptstyle}
  {\xcirc\scriptscriptstyle}
  {\xcirc\scriptscriptstyle}
}}
\newcommand{\xcirc}[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{$#1\latexcirc$}}}
\let\circ\ccirc
```

You need to comment out only the last line in case you want to return back to the default.

Comment: Thank you. This also works for me. What is the defference between this one and the answer above?

Comment: @AntillarMaximus My answer uses more efficient ways for selecting a smaller circle and spacing it; moreover it works also in subscripts and superscripts, which Count Zero's doesn't.

Comment: How could I let `\circ` be your `\ccirc` but keeping the usual `\circ` in `\oldcirc` but avoiding `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].` when compiling my document?

Comment: @Manuel You need to use a "copy" of `\circ`. I added a workaround

Answer (score 3):

My solution is this:

```
\newcommand{\ccirc}{\kern0.5ex\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptstyle\circ$}}\kern0.5ex}
```

in the preamble and then:

```
\begin{align}
\forall\ a,b,c \in S,\ a\ccirc(b\ccirc c)= (a\ccirc b)\ccirc c
\end{align}
```

It may seem convoluted, but `\circ` requires math mode, so with `\scriptstyle` you can set the size. Then `\vcenter` does some silly thing inserting huge horizontal spaces to the point where the rest of the equation is off the page, so I must force it with `\hbox` to behave. If I just left it like that, the symbols next to the newly defined `\ccirc` would be too close, so I added some kerning. Whew!... `:)`

Of course, you can fiddle with the size, by using a different command from `\scriptsize`.

Comment: Why not `\newcommand{\ccirc}{\kern0.5ex\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptstyle\circ$}}\kern0.5ex}`?  Seems a little less convoluted and still achieves the same effect.

Comment: Wouldn't `\mathbin` help better than that pair of `\kern0.5ex` spacings?

Comment: But if you put it in a limit `\lim_{f \ccirc g}` it's weird. It doesn't fit good.

Comment: @Manuel: The problem is that `\scriptstyle` doesn't set the style relatively, so it won't fit it to the subscript you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As shown [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27766), there is a simple way to do this kind of thing using the `relsize` package.

```
\usepackage{relsize}
\newcommand*{\mycirc}{\mathrel{\mathsmaller{\mathsmaller{\circ}}}}
```